# jQuery replace with variable?

Tags: jquery, replace

I'm trying to do a `replace` on a string like this:

```
$('#example_id').replace(/abc123/g,'something else')
```

But the `abc123` actually needs to be a variable.

So something like:

```
var old_string = 'abc123'
$('#example_id').replace(/old_string/g,'something else')
```

So how would I use a variable in the replace function?

Comment: Do you need to use a regular expression? If so, be aware that if old_string contained any meaningful regular expression characters such as `(`, `)`, `*`, `.`, `-`, etc will need to be escaped or will probably break your replace.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First of `$('#example_id')` will give you a jQuery object, you must be replacing string inside its html or value. Try this.

```
var re = new RegExp("abc123","g");
$('#example_id').html($('#example_id').html().replace(re, "something else"));
```

Answer (score 2):

There is another version of replace which takes a `RegExp` object. This object can be built up from a string literal:

```
var old_string = "abc123";
var myregexp = new RegExp(old_string,'g');
$('#example_id').replace(myregexp,'something else')
```

Some useful info [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html)

Answer (score 0):

Create a `RegExp` object:

```
var regexp = new RegExp(old_string, 'g');
$('#example_id').replace(regexp,'something else');
```

**Edit:** Fixed parameters

Comment: the constructor for RegExp does not need the leading and trailing `/` and the `g` should be the second argument. [Javascript RegExp Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Answer (score 0):

You can create regular expression using constructor.

```
var re = new RegExp('abc123', 'g')
$('#example_id').replace(re,'something else')
```

Here is [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) documentation.

For replacing element's inner html content you can use html method:

```
$('#example_id').html(function(i, s){return s.replace(re, 'replace with')})
```